# Blazor Microsoft Entra ID get user data

Tags: graphql, microsoft-entra-id

I have registered my Blazor Server application in the Microsoft Entra ID and I want to retrieve the authenticated user's data (name, email, ID, etc.). I have tried this code, but it is not a good solution:

```
[Inject]
GraphServiceClient GraphServiceClient { get; set; }
[Inject]
MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler { get; set; }
private Guid _userId;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    try {
         var user = await GraphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        _userId = new Guid(user.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I open the page, it reloads while querying user data, causing a white blank screen to flash up.

**Solution**

```
public interface IUserService
{
    string Email { get; }
    string FullName { get; }
    Guid Id { get; }
    Task InitializeAsync();
}


public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public UserService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var authenticationState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authenticationState.User;

        Email = user.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value ?? "???";
        FullName = user.FindFirst("name")?.Value ?? "???";
        Id = new Guid(user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")?.Value ?? "");
    }
}
```

In Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

In use:

```
[Inject]
IUserService UserService { get; set; }
...
var userId = UserService.Id;
```